# App works on browser but not on device CORS issue? No network activity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app.

The app works fine in the browser but on device the http requests don't load. When i inspect the app with safari remote debugging there are no errors. The network tab is empty, first after a refresh the files are listed there.

For some strange reason the api request to the weather api doesnt work.

This:

```
$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + loc.lat + '&lon=' + loc.lng + '&units=metric&&APPID=XXX').success(function(weatherf) {
            $scope.weatherf = weatherf;

            alert("YUP");
}).error(function(err) {
        $state.go("error");
   });
```

The "YUP" and the error function doesn't get called. What could cause this?
I have the white list plugin installed and have this in my config.xml:

```
 <access origin="*"/>
 <allow-intent href="*"/>
 <allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

I work with ionic 1.7.15 and cordova 6.0.0
Please comment if you need more information.

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Is it in iOS device?

Comment: both, android and iOS

Comment: try this in config.xml - <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" /> </platform>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update content security policy meta tag for it. Please add your hostname as src-script 'hostname';

Comment: Like this?    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">

Comment: yes. if abc.com is your hostname then script-src 'abc.com'

Comment: what if i have multiple hosts?

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: you can write script-src 'host1.com' 'host2.com';